# MVC style validation issue

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, materialize

I am using the `materializecss` plugin to build my interface. I am trying to validate a textbox as an email input but I am getting the following issue when I hit the `Tab` button:
[image]

Controller:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "You need to type your e-mail address!"), DisplayName("E-mail address")]
[StringLength(64)]
[EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "This is not a valid e-mail address!")]
public string ACC_MADDR { get; set; }
```

HTML:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ACC_MADDR, new { id = "reg_email", @class = "validate", autocomplete = "off", maxlength = "64", required = "required", data_length = 64, @type = "email" })
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ACC_MADDR, new { data_error = @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ACC_MADDR) })
```

Comment: you should be using @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.xxxxxx) instead of  labelFor

Comment: I am using it in the `data-error` attribute. The materializecss module uses a label "E-mail" (see picture) as a placeholder for the textbox and the `data-error` attribute to display errors under the textbox